# count multiple value in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, tableau-api

I have a dataframe that shows answers of a multiple choice question of 5 students:

```
id     Question 1
0          a;b;c
1          a;c
2          b
3          a;d
4          b;c;d
```

And I want to count how many times does a choice been selected. For example, the final answer should be

```
a:3
b:3
c:3
d:2
```

So is there a quick way to get the solution using python?

Besides, I am using the data from the dataframe for visualization in Tableau. Tableau counts like this:

```
a;b;c appear once
a;c   appear once
b     appear once
a;d   appear once
b;c;d appear once
```

So is there a way to get the above result directly using Tableau? Or I have to do something in python then using tableau.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below code to count the occurrence of each choice in a pandas dataframe column:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'id':[0, 1,2,3,4], 'Question1':['a;b;c','a;c','b','a;d','b;c;d']})
count = data.Question1.str.split(';', expand=True).stack().value_counts()
```

output:

```
a    3
b    3
c    3
d    2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also use get dummies

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'id':[0, 1,2,3,4], 'Question1':['a;b;c','a;c','b','a;d','b;c;d']}) 
data['Question1'].str.get_dummies(sep=';').sum()
```

**output**

```
a    3
b    3
c    3
d    2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this also:-

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'id':[0, 1,2,3,4], 'Question1':['a;b;c','a;c','b','a;d','b;c;d']})

temp_list = []
for var in data['Question1'].values:
    for x in var.split(';'):
        temp_list.append(x)
value, count = np.unique(temp_list, return_counts=True)
for v,c in zip(value, count):
    print(f"{v} -->> {c}")
```

**Output**

```
a -->> 3
b -->> 3
c -->> 3
d -->> 2
```